# vb.net How to extract text from the textbox

Tags: vb.net, text, split

In the textbox I have

external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBitTwGIFdSUoa1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi-download.com%2Fgatekeeper%2FW3siZSI6MTQ5OTkyNTc4MSwiZCI6InNodXR0ZXJzdG9jay1tZWRpYSIsImsiOiJwaG90b1wvNDE3NDM0NDQzXC9tZWRpdW0uanBnIiwibSI6MH0sIlBZRG5JV2RoM2FhU09MS0FQVzUzRjFGTjhqMCJd%2Fshutterstock_417434443.jpg%3Ftoken%3Dexp%3D1499925781%7Eacl%3D%2Fgatekeeper%2FW3siZSI6MTQ5OTkyNTc4MSwiZCI6InNodXR0ZXJzdG9jay1tZWRpYSIsImsiOiJwaG90b1wvNDE3NDM0NDQzXC9tZWRpdW0uanBnIiwibSI6MH0sIlBZRG5JV2RoM2FhU09MS0FQVzUzRjFGTjhqMCJd%2Ftest_417434443.jpg%2A%7Ehmac%3D7bab702bc0ef6b59b90061f22552226e8671410b&_nc_hash=AQC6jPXsLA9PVA_F

I want to get this out

api-download.com/gatekeeper/W3siZSI6MTQ5OTkyNTc4MSwiZCI6InNodXR0ZXJzdG9jay1tZWRpYSIsImsiOiJwaG90b1wvNDE3NDM0NDQzXC9tZWRpdW0uanBnIiwibSI6MH0sIlBZRG5JV2RoM2FhU09MS0FQVzUzRjFGTjhqMCJd/test_417434443.jpg

How do I do this directly from vb.net

Comment: Well, get the index for "api-" position and from there, find the next index for ".jpg".  If you are having problems with that, post your attempted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string is url encoded.

If you url decode the string it will become more readable, which in fact this site picks up as url and automatically links.

> external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBitTwGIFdSUoa1&url=http://api-download.com/gatekeeper/W3siZSI6MTQ5OTkyNTc4MSwiZCI6InNodXR0ZXJzdG9jay1tZWRpYSIsImsiOiJwaG90b1wvNDE3NDM0NDQzXC9tZWRpdW0uanBnIiwibSI6MH0sIlBZRG5JV2RoM2FhU09MS0FQVzUzRjFGTjhqMCJd/shutterstock_417434443.jpg?token=exp=1499925781~acl=/gatekeeper/W3siZSI6MTQ5OTkyNTc4MSwiZCI6InNodXR0ZXJzdG9jay1tZWRpYSIsImsiOiJwaG90b1wvNDE3NDM0NDQzXC9tZWRpdW0uanBnIiwibSI6MH0sIlBZRG5JV2RoM2FhU09MS0FQVzUzRjFGTjhqMCJd/test_417434443.jpg*~hmac=7bab702bc0ef6b59b90061f22552226e8671410b&_nc_hash=AQC6jPXsLA9PVA_F

You can now see that the portion you are looking for is the URL query.

The easiest way to clean up the string you want and get the value you want is by adding a reference to System.Web.Dll to your project and importing System.Web to your class.

Then you can use the shared methods from `Utility` to clean the string up and then parse it into a collection of values.

In between create a new `URI` so you can read the query string property that you want to parse.

```
Dim original = "external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBitTwGIFdSUoa1&url=http://api-download.com/gatekeeper/W3siZSI6MTQ5OTkyNTc4MSwiZCI6InNodXR0ZXJzdG9jay1tZWRpYSIsImsiOiJwaG90b1wvNDE3NDM0NDQzXC9tZWRpdW0uanBnIiwibSI6MH0sIlBZRG5JV2RoM2FhU09MS0FQVzUzRjFGTjhqMCJd/shutterstock_417434443.jpg?token=exp=1499925781~acl=/gatekeeper/W3siZSI6MTQ5OTkyNTc4MSwiZCI6InNodXR0ZXJzdG9jay1tZWRpYSIsImsiOiJwaG90b1wvNDE3NDM0NDQzXC9tZWRpdW0uanBnIiwibSI6MH0sIlBZRG5JV2RoM2FhU09MS0FQVzUzRjFGTjhqMCJd/test_417434443.jpg*~hmac=7bab702bc0ef6b59b90061f22552226e8671410b&_nc_hash=AQC6jPXsLA9PVA_F"
    Dim decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(original)
    Dim ul = New Uri("http://" & decoded)

    Dim col = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(ul.Query)
    Dim whatIWant = col("url") ' this is the value that you want.
```